# How to send array POST/GET parameter with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to send a data like this to a rest Webservice :

```
let params = {
    uri: getWsUrl(),
    body:queryString.stringify({
       city: 885,
       customer: user.id,
       basket: [
           [
          product_id: 448025,
          count: 2
           ]
       ]
    })
};
```

I use `request.post(params, function(...))` method for send parameter to Webservice. After sending this request to the server, I get the parameters with $_POST But `basket` is empty!
Can you help me?

Comment: Please add the options you are giving to > request.post

Answer (score 0):

For sending data in response use render, consider the following example

```
 response.end(JSON.stringify({'title': 'Welcome', 'subtitle': "Users List", 'user': result}));
```

Comment: Try response.end(); . Are you rendering any view with it .

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send a nested array as if it were an object.

You have two option. Either change the array inside the array to an object.

`city: 885,
    customer: user.id,
    basket: [
         {
         product_id: 448025,
         count: 2
         } //HERE
       ]
    }`

Or if you really want that array in there (please don't. Try to keep your data as flat as possible.

You can do this (not recommended). Just wrap it in an object

`city: 885,
       customer: user.id,
       basket: [
           [{
          product_id: 448025,
          count: 2
           }]
       ]
    }`